# Javascript - factorize code with many times repeated js block

Tags: javascript, ruby, erb

I have a pretty basic javascript code but I repeat the same chunk of code many times
As a sidenote, I am using ruby as backend code.

How can I factorize it in my file example.js

```
<% if x= 0 %>
var msg;
msg = Messenger().post({

  <% if  y = 2 %>    
    message:  'example',
    type:     'error',
    hideAfter: 3000
  <% elsif y = 3 and z =5%>
    message:  'example',
    type:     'error',
    hideAfter: 3000
  <% else %>
    message: 'different'
    type: 'different'

<% elsif y>2 and y < 7  %>
    <% if  y = 2 %>    
    message:  'example',
    type:     'error',
    hideAfter: 3000
  <% elsif y = 3 and z =5%>
    message:  'example',
    type:     'error',
    hideAfter: 3000
  <% else %>
    message: 'different'
    type: 'different'

<% else %>
 you're a cool dude
<% end %>
```

It's just an example but I don't know how to simply replace a large chunk of code by a very short attribute and re-Use it

I think it's not possible but that's what I would like to do in the spirit:

```
CHUNK= 
    message:  'example',
    type:     'error',
    hideAfter: 3000


<% if x= 0 %>
var msg;
msg = Messenger().post({

  <% if  y = 2 %>    
    CHUNK
  <% elsif y = 3 and z =5%>
    CHUNK
  <% else %>
    message: 'different'
    type: 'different'

<% elsif y>2 and y < 7  %>
    CHUNK
  <% elsif y = 3 and z =7%>
    soso
  <% else %>
    CHUNK

<% else %>
 you're a cool dude
<% end %>
```

Is it possible to factorize code when you have a similar chunk of code that gets repeated many many times like above. How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything is possible. Furthermore, it is generally a good idea to remove code duplication. DRY is one of Rail's underlying principles.

However, you have 2 more serious issues here:

1. There are 2 different languages in 1 file
2. You have too much logic in the view

Here's how I would fix #2. I prefer to use early returns instead of nested `if/else/elsif`. This code would go in a separate file, perhaps a view helper.

```
def message_for y, z
  if y == 2
    return { message:  'example',
             type:     'error',
             hideAfter: 3000 }
    ...
```

If you make this method available to your view, you can use

```
<%= message_for y, z %>
```

Having said that, you can also reuse `chunk`.

```
<% @chunk = { message:  'example',
              type:     'error',
              hideAfter: 3000 } %>
```

Comment: I simplified it so that people who are not Rails people understand. My file is actually a .js.erb so ruby is interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

It should be doable. Your `post` function is accepting an object, so you could do:

```
var chunkA = {
  message:  'example',
  type:     'error',
  hideAfter: 3000
}

// the rest of your reusable chunks
```

Then you could call it as follows:

```
var msg = Messenger().post(
  <% if  y = 2 %>  
    chunkA  
  <% elsif y = 3 and z=5 %>
    chunkB
  <% end %>
  // etc.
);
```

Edit: While this answers OP's question, a better approach to this problem is to move the logic into your controller. See B Seven's answer for an explanation.

Comment: I like this answer. It's not really clear why the question uses 2 different languages. Perhaps the best solution is to keep it in Javascript.